# Why is the following sequence of random varables stopping time?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times

Given an adapted cadlag Levy Process $X$ and a constant $C$ defined as the $\sup_{t} |\Delta X_t|$ where $\Delta X_t=X_t- X_{t^-}$  and the book defines:

$T_1=\inf\{t:|X_t| \geq C\} $

$\vdots$

$T_{n+1}=\inf \{t>T_n: |X_t-X_{T_n}| \geq C\}$

My attempt:
I proceed by induction

Since X is cadlag adapted, $T_1$ is clearly a stopping time.
Then I assume that $T_n$ is a stopping time and try to conclude that $T_{n+1}$ is a also a stopping time

$\{T_{n+1} \leq t\}= \bigcup_{s \in (T_n,t]\cap \mathbb{Q}} \big\{ \{T_n <t\} \cap\{|X_s-X_{T_n}| \geq C\} \big\} $

If the above two sets are equal?(I am not absolutely sure if they are!!)
then since by assumption that $T_n $ is a stopping time we have that  $\{T_n <t\} \in \mathcal{F}_t$ and since X is adapted $X_s$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$ measurable since $s\leq t$. Also on the set $\{T_n<t\} $ we have that $X_{T_n}$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$ measurable since $X_{T_n}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{T_n}$ measurable($X$ is cadlag adapted).

The countable union is still in $\mathcal{F}_t$ and we are done.

Is this proof valid? Can you point out where the problem is and how could I fix it?

Comment: I don't understand why $T_1$ is a stopping time. $C$ seems to be a (random) constant which depends on the entire path: it's the largest jump in your process.Asking yourself whether you are taller now than you will ever be able to jump does not seem a question you can answer with the information of today. (Maybe this comparison is clear only to me :D)

Comment: @Corn no it's not random . Its deterministic independent of the path , a universal constant for this stochastic process

Comment: @corn if we know the supremum of jumps is 5  , then asking yourself if the jump until today was less than equal to 5 is something that I know until .Does this make sense ?

Comment: You are definitely right, given that C is not random. But what I still don't understand is why $C (\omega)= sup_{t \ge 0} |\Delta X_t (\omega)|$ is actually not random. Or is it given in the exercise that the supremum is bounded by some deterministic constant?